# Can you return a function in flask as well as return render_template?

Tags: python, flask

When you are within an @app.route in Flask, can you return a value for your function in addition to returning render_template?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do so directly - return value of function decorated with `@app.route` is automatically passed back by Flask as a page to the client (render_template return value is actually a HTML string representing the page), and the control flow is such that you can't simply "pass" arguments to a different `@app.route`. What you **can** do though, is store whatever you need in a global variable than  can be accessed by different functions.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful response and clarification.

Comment: Some care is required using a global variable if the application is used by multiple users.

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb, could you give me an example of the concern you have in mind where there might be multiple users?

Comment: @SentBackInTime say two users visit the URL at the same time, and the function produces different results for each: you can't be sure that the value of the global variable will be correct for both.  It may be better to store the value in a cookie or [session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).